# Python While Loop attempts restart to 0 if successful

Tags: python, while-loop, exponential-backoff

So I am learning exponential backoff, my code was running too fast and causing api limit errors I created this function and it works. but I want it once it is successful, attempts should be 0 again, right now every time theres an error it justs add one more to attempts and it stops after the 5 try. How can I make attempts =0 again once it is successful ?

Thank you for your help

```
def retry(func, retries=5): 
    def retry_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        attempts = 0
        while attempts < retries:
            try:
                return func(*args, **kwargs) 
                attempts = 0
            except:
                print(f'error {attempts}')
                time.sleep(20)
                attempts += 1
    return retry_wrapper
```

Comment: Any code below a `return` is unreachable. The definition of `return` is that that's the last line executed in a function. Putting anything below it will never do anything. Your `attempts = 0` code below `return func(*args, **kwargs)` will never execute.

Comment: `attempts` goes out of scope as soon as `retry_wrapper` returns anyway, so there's no point in changing its value once `func` succeeds.

Comment: The next time you call the decorated function, it will get its own fresh `attempts = 0` before the loop is entered.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so there is something you need to know about the `return` method, once it is run, it doesn't run code after it, so if I have this:

```
def test():
    return "hi"
    print("Hello")
print(test())
```

I will only get `hi`, not `hello`, because the function stops running when return is called, its similar in a way to `break` to escape a loop, so you need to put whatever you want to do before the return, *always*.

```
try:
    attempts = 0
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
```

So your code should look like this

Comment: Thank you tygzy I didn't know that. I tried adding it before the return but it just runs indefinitely:

Presentation Boards
error 0
error 0
error 0

Comment: That means that you aren't getting an error then since it isn't running the code that increments `attempts` by 1

Comment: @tygzy: You are always setting `attempts` to 0.

Comment: Not really, it prints as error 0, error 0, error 0 then a few successful attempts and then again error 0, etc... It should be error 0, error 1, error 2 and if it reaches 5 consecutive errors then it should stop

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the result from the decorated function after resetting `attempts`:

```
def retry(func, retries=5): 
    def retry_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        attempts = 0
        while attempts < retries:
            try:
                res = func(*args, **kwargs)
                # in case func fails, the except block is executed immediately
                attempts = 0
                return res
            except:
                print(f'error {attempts}')
                time.sleep(20)
                attempts += 1
    return retry_wrapper
```

Comment: Hey Maurice and thank you for your help. attempts doesn't reset to 0 it just keeps counting.

Comment: I doubt that, there is something else wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to reset `attempts` at all; you only need it while the current attempt at calling `func` is failing. Once it succeeds, `retry_wrapper` returns, and won't be called again until the *next* time you explicitly call `func`, at which point you get 5 fresh attempts again.

You may as well just use a `for` loop as well, and `retries` doesn't need to be an argument (though see below if you want to pass a different number).

```
def retry(func): 
    def retry_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        retries = 5
        for attempt in range(retries):
            try:
                return func(*args, **kwargs) 
            except Exception:
                print(f'error {attempt}')
                time.sleep(20)
        raise RuntimeException(f"Failure after {retries} attempts")
    return retry_wrapper


@retry
def some_function(...):
    ...

some_function("foo")  # You get 5 tries to succeed
some_function("bar")  # You get another 5 tries to succeed
```

To parameterize the decorator on the number of attempts, you need an extra layer of indirection, as the return value of `retry(whatever)`, not `retry` itself, should receive the function as an argument.

```
def retry(retries=5):
    def _(func):
        def retry_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            for attempt in range(retries):
                try:
                    return func(*args, **kwargs)
                except Exception:
                    print(f'error {attempt}')
                    time.sleep(20)
            raise RuntimeException(f"Failure after {retries} attempts")
        return retry_wrapper
    return _

# 5 tries to succeed
@retry()
def foo1():
    ...

# 10 tries to succeed
@retry(10):
def foo2():
    ...
```